# Can't use a variable inside static variable definition?

Tags: php, static-variables

`static $PATH_TO_USER = $server . '/users';`

I'm getting a syntax error. If I remove the static, it accepts it, though.

It's not a big deal to type the whole thing out, but I'm not sure why this isn't working in the first place

Comment: Is this declaration included inside a class definition ? or is $server a global ?

Comment: The first answer to this question answers everything what you need to know about the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Static variable

> Static variables may be declared as seen in the examples above. Trying to assign values to these variables which are the result of **expressions will cause a parse error**.

via the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

#### Static property

> Like any other PHP static variable,
>   static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or
>   constant; **expressions are not allowed**.

via the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).